# Unable to write dumpcap output to mounted drive

Tags: automounting, read-write

[image]

I managed to automount an exFAT drive with `rw` permissions. The mount point is a directory I made (`/media/usb1`) and the drive itself is named `usb1`.

```shell
sudo dumpcap -i eth1  -w /media/usb1/logs -b duration:600 -b  files:100
```

Yet I get this error when running:

```
dumpcap: The file to which the capture would be saved could not be opened: No such file or directory.
```

I suspect the issue is specifically with writing to the external drive, but this code worked for a while before it seemed to arbitrarily stop.
I'm looking over other resources but I can't find anything related to this specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

Create using `touch`:

```
sudo touch /media/usb1/logs && sudo dumpcap -i eth1 -w /media/usb1/logs -b duration:600 -b files:100
```

If touch failed and GUI file creation works, is `logs` supposed to be a folder? Then you need `/media/run/logs/logs` the second `logs` being a file. You could use an extension for ease of clarity. `/media/run/logs/dumpcap.log`

```
sudo dumpcap -i eth1 -w /media/run/logs/dumpcap.log -b duration:600 -b files:100
```

You could go one farther. Use a timestamped file and checking for the directory.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

#Set variable for timestamp
unique_id=$(date +"%Y_%m_%d-%H_%M_%S")

#Check for directory, make if needed
if [[ ! -d /run/media/logs ]]; then
sudo mkdir -p /run/media/logs
fi

#Create variable for file with timestamp
session_log=(sudo touch /run/media/logs/dumpcap_"$unique_id".log)

sudo dumpcap -i eth1 -w "$session_log" -b duration:600 -b files:100

exit 0
```

Save to: `my_dumpcap_log.sh`
Then: `chmod +x my_dumpcap_log.sh`
Finally, run: `./my_dumpcap_log.sh`

Comment: This did not fix the issue, unfortunately.
I'm beginning to think it has an issue with mounting but I didn't change the permissions or automounting code. All of that worked at one point.

Comment: Same error?  sudo is used on both commands, permissions is unlikely.

Comment: Yes. It is the same error

Comment: @JohnnyC Try using /run/media/$USER/...usb1, maybe...  check this path.

Comment: Is this a directory I should add? (doesn't already exist)

Comment: Nah, look in the directory. `cd /run/media/$USER/` that's where my usb drives show up.  Right now the card reader plugged in reads LinuxFS because it has a volume label.  It can show up as a lot of names.  If there is no label, it's generally usb1, usb2..etc.

Comment: It mounts to /media/usb1

Comment: Is there some kind of write protection on the usb drive?  is it a SD card with a lock button, by chance?

Comment: The USB drive worked fine until it didn't. That's part of my confusion. It automounted and then dumpcap wrote to it. I tried putting everything back and came back with no data written to it

Comment: Can you open the usb drive in file manager and create files and folders?

Comment: Yes. I have made a folder and file without issue on the USB.

Comment: You don't need a folder it doesn't look like.  Not unless logs is supposed to be a folder.  Then you need `/media/run/logs/logs` the second `logs` being a file.  You could use an extension for ease of clarity.  `/media/run/logs/dumpcap.log`

Comment: so before I had this issue it wrote straight to /media/usb1. I tried to make the logs folder to see if that would fix anything. If I alter the code to what it was originally, it should have no issue writing?

Original code:
#!/bin/bash
sleep 6
while :
do
sudo dumpcap -i eth1  -w /media/usb1/PIS_`date_+"%d-%m-%Y-%T"`.pcapng -b duration:600 -b  files:100

done

Comment: Haha. That's what I was doing is telling you exactly this.  

Comment: That's what has me perplexed. Why would this stop working? I have five units and they all stopped working, though this code was fine for a time.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd need the sleep command, but you are right, it does look like the command's should work.

Comment: It allows the unit to sync with the time server before starting the logs. Otherwise the time is arbitrary and our vendor cannot make sense of when faults in the system occurred

Comment: So, neither script is working?  That is super odd.  You can try `sudo chown -R youruser:youruser /media` to double check the access ownership isn't root on the group.  I've seen that happen... But, yeah, wayyy strange.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a go. Appreciate all your assistance

Comment: Anytime man, good luck!

Comment: the additional "sudo" command in the file seemed to have borked it(?) Removed it and now it is working as intended.